Why is the iOS devices button no longer appearing in iTunes on Windows?
Previously when any of my iOS devices (eg iPhone, iPad) is connected to my Windows PC, a device button would appear.
But since yesterday, none of my iPhone or iPad button have appeared there. I've tried to update to the latest iOS, but it's still not showing.
Does anyone know what's wrong with it?


Would you let me know why my post was downvoted?
